# Problem using ioredis scanStream() to scan through all Redis keys

Tags: node.js, redis, ioredis

I am trying to sync all Redis keys with MongoDB in a NodeJS application.

I am using ioredis as the NodeJS Redis client, and tried to achieve the above by using the [scanStream() function](https://github.com/luin/ioredis#streamify-scanning). This function is supposedly an easier way to scan through all the keys in a cursor by using streams.

This is the code that I am using to try to scan through all the keys:

```
const stream = await redis.scanStream();
stream.on("data", async (resultKeys) => {
  await stream.pause();
  for (let i = 0; i < resultKeys.length; i++) {
    try {
      let KEY = resultKeys[i];
      let redisObjectStr = await redis.get(KEY);
      let redisObject = JSON.parse(redisObjectStr);

      // Sync Redis key with MongoDB
      const user = await User.findOne({
        apiKey: KEY
      }).exec();

      if (user) {
        user.color = redisObject.color;
        user.size = redisObject.size;
        await user.save();
        await stream.resume();
      }
    } catch (err) {
      next(err)
    }
  }
});
stream.on("end", () => {
  console.log("all keys have been visited")
  res.send("done")
})
```

However I am getting the following error:

> api_1      | all keys have been visited proxy_1    | 172.18.0.1 - -
>   [22/Jan/2019:12:52:06 +0000] "GET /api/syncredis HTTP/1.1" 200 4 "-"
>   "PostmanRuntime/7.6.0" "-" api_1      | ::ffff:172.18.0.6 - -
>   [22/Jan/2019:12:52:06 +0000] "GET /api/syncredis HTTP/1.1" 200 4 "-"
>   "PostmanRuntime/7.6.0" api_1      | SyntaxError: Unexpected token l in
>   JSON at position 0 api_1      |     at JSON.parse () api_1 
>   |     at ScanStream.stream.on
>   (/usr/src/app/routes/testRoute.js:428:32) api_1      |     at
>   process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:77:7)
>   api_1      | Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after
>   they are sent to the client

Comment: It`s seems some of your keys in redis has not JSON format in they data. Or the other case - some of them is not the string keys and redis.get will fail.

Comment: Is it complaining about this line, `res.send("done")`, which is not `send`'ing JSON? What does the `res` reference point to?

Answer (score 4):

I assume that you are using a simple redis and not a clustered one. You should try to wrap it in a promise so that it dosent jump to stream.end directly and also put a check on result that you get from redis.get, check that it is a proper parsable json string or not.

I would suggest to get all keys from a different function and then iterate on all the keys syncing it with mongo.

Code :-

```
let arrOfKeys = await getKeys(prefix);
//loop through all the keys and sync with mongo 

const getKeys = async (prefix = "") => {
    let finalKeyArray = [], keysArray = [];
    let stream = redis.scanStream({
        match: prefix
    });
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        stream.on("data", async (keys = []) => {
            let key;
            for (key of keys) {
                if (!keysArray.includes(key)) {
                    await keysArray.push(key);
                }
            }
        });
        stream.on("end", () => {
            res(keysArray);
        });
    }).then((keysets) => {
        keysets.forEach((keySet) => {
            keySet.forEach((key) => {
                if (!finalKeyArray.includes(key)) {
                    finalKeyArray.push(key);
                }
            })
        })
        return finalKeyArray;
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.error("Error while getting redis keys:", err);
        return [];
    });
}
```